Proof of Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem in Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability
The proof is written allowing for a state space that is an arbitrary measurable space, but I am interested in the case of real valued stochastic processes.
I am working through the proof of the theorem, where we are in the process of trying to show that finite dimensional distributions defined on $\mathbb{R}^F$ can be extended onto $\mathbb{R}^T$ where $T$ is an arbitrary index set and $F\subset T$ with $F$ finite.
On page 441: "First an easy proof will be given if the $(S_t, \mathcal{B}_t)$ are all standard measurable spaces, such as $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. So we can assume that $S_t$ are all compact metric spaces with Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Thus $S_T$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem (2.2.8)."
Surely this is an error because $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, hence we cannot invoke Tychonoff's theorem that $R^T$ is compact.
Also it is not even clear to me how the definition given a standard measurable space given on page 440 can be correct because a counterexample would be again be $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
Am I right in saying we just need to replace the word "compact" with the word "complete" and ignore the part where Tychonoff's theorem is used and instead try and show that the product of complete metric spaces is complete?
Thanks for any help.

$\mathbf{R} \subset [-\infty, \infty]$ and your stochastic process is extended in the obvious way (i.e., $P(|X_t| = \infty$ for any $t) =0$). (However, I agree with you that doing this is very awkward.) A few years ago I wrote, in Spanish, a proof of Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem for complete, separable, metrizable spaces, without appealing to Tychonoff's theorem. The proof is 15 pages long, but most of the proof are prerequisites of analysis. The proof of the actual theorem is "just" 4 pages long.

In the definition of a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$ being standard, it's important to note that we can take a different topology $\tau$ on $X$ as long as $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{B}(\tau)$ remains true. In the proof of Proposition 12.1.1, Dudley essentially constructs a different topology on $\mathbb{R}$, yet $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ remains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to this new topology.

@HirofumiShiba I see that the sets he describes form a base for a topology $\mathcal{T}_{[0,1]}$ on [0,1]. But then it should be the case that there is a measurable bijection $f:[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that the topology induced by $f$, namely $\mathcal{T}f:={f(U); U \in \mathcal{T}{[0,1]}}$ generates the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and I don't see it. I know it's going to be user error here, but I am stumped.

@WilliamM. But isn't this cheating a little bit? He extends the measure onto $\mathbb{R}^T$ not $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^T$ unless I am missing something.

Oh no! These sets don’t form a base! They might form a subbase on $[0,1]$, but that is not the point. He is describing how to construct a mapping.

@HirofumiShiba sorry subbase*.

The measurable space $\big([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1])\big)$ is an example where the space $[0,1]$ with its usual topology is compact, and $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ is (of course) the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated from this topology.
Therefore, the proof strategy in Proposition 12.1.1 is to construct a Borel measurable mapping $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not continuous. With such a $f$, we can induce a weaker topology on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted as $f_*\tau:=\{f(U)\subset\mathbb{R}\mid U\in\tau\}$, that makes $(\mathbb{R},f_*\tau)$ compact but doesn't change its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{B}(f_*\tau)$.
The Construction of $f$
The partitions
$$
[0,1]=\{0\}\sqcup\left(\bigsqcup_{m=1}^\infty I_m\right),\qquad I_m:=\left(\frac{1}{m+1},\frac{1}{m}\right],
$$
$$
\mathbb{R}=\{0\}\sqcup\left(\bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty(J^{+}_n\cup J_n^{-})\right),\qquad J^+_n:=(n,n+1],J^-_n:=[-n-1,-n),
$$
that Dudley described in his proof, are used to construct the function $f$.
Define the function $f$ on the intervals $I_{2m}$ and $I_{2m-1}$ by
$$f|_{I_{2m-1}}:I_{2m-1}\to J^+_m,\quad f|_{I_{2m}}:I_{2m}\to J^-_m,\qquad m=1,2,\cdots,$$
where $f|_{I_{2m-1}}$ and $f|_{I_{2m}}$ are arbitrary continuous bijections. Thus constructed function $f$ is also a bijection, and continuous almost everywhere, except on the set
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{m}\in[0,1]\,\middle|\,m=1,2,\cdots\right\}=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\partial I_m
$$
that is of measure zero. Hence, $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable. $\blacksquare$

Great, thanks for your help
